# How to apply a rule to only one component in altium?

Tags: altium, design-rules

I would leave the insulation of copper with 0.35 mm across the board except in a microcontroller. It requires that the insulation allowed is 0.2 mm because of the distances between the pad. How to make a rule unique to this component?
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can apply a rule to a particular footprint, or to a component with a particular designator. But that won't apply to the traces connected to the part, just the pads of the component itself.

Answer (score 2):

As this problem regards with the footprint itself, instead of being a problem of a whole net or component, you can proceed making a rule just for the footprint.

I've done this with success:

1. Design > Rules > Clearance > New Rule
2. Change the new rule priority to the highest, or if you have plenty rules, arrange it correctly to make it work.
3. Enter the new rule properties with double click
4. In "Where The First Object Matches", select "Custom Query"
5. Write "HasFootprint('NameOfYourFootprint')
6. Set the desired values in the Constraints tab, then accept.

Now we are going to re run the design rule checker.

7. Tools > Reset Error Markers
8. Tools > Design Rule Checker > Run Design Rule Check

Hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a room, then use the "WithinRoom" query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put a directive via a box around the MCU on the schematic to assign a net class to the nets associated with the MCU using a **Blanket Directive** and then apply the rule to that net class, however it will relax the clearance rules for all parts of those nets anywhere on the PCB.

If you are willing to be a little less automated, you can run DRC for the board, confirm that the only errors are those associated with the footprint, then relax the rule. If editing happens subsequently, traces will be allowed to be closer anywhere on the PCB of course.